# difference btween two filter for match section in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using mongodb match query for filter result.this is my match query

```
var List = await ConnectionHandler.MongoCollectionScoreCardDataBSON.Aggregate<BsonDocument>()
                    .Match(filter).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Supplier", Supplier) 
                    & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("FileType", FileType) 
                    & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte("ReportDate", "ISODate(\"" + stdt + "\")") 
                    & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Lt("ReportDate", "ISODate(\"" + stdt + "\")");
```

or,

```
string filter = "{Supplier:"DIPLOMAT",FileType:"SHIPMENT",ReportDate:{$gte:ISODate("2017-05-01"),$lt:ISODate("2017-06-01")}}"
```

what is the difference between this two fiter.. I get different result for these two filter in match query in mongodb and failed to identify the reason.

What I am missing here and from which way it is different?

Comment: You get different results because one simply does not work. This `"ISODate(\""` is a "string". MongoDB query arguments are not "strings" unless the actual data type is such. You actually want to provide a native `Date` object. `ISODate()` is just a mongodb shell method that creates a JavaScript based `Date` object. And that is simply because the shell uses JavaScript. You need to supply a native date type for c# as the argument.

Comment: See [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: ow. I understand. thank you for your answer. should i delete this question ?

Comment: You can do whatever you want really.